# how to count and print all palindrome word from a file

Tags: python

I am trying to check if the words of the file are palindromes or not, if yes then it should print those words and their total count.but when I run the code its not showing result. please help me with this.

```
def findPalindrome(): 
    list3=list() 
    for line in open("English.txt"): 
        list1 = line.strip() 
        list2 = list1.split() 
    for x in list2: 
        if isPalindrome(x): 
        list3.append(x) 
     return list3
```

it should print all the palindrome words that are in text file, plus their count.

Comment: A sample of your txt file along with your efforts?

Comment: *"please help me with this."* Help with what? You have not shown your code, so how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: def findPalindrome():
    list3=list()
    for line in open("English.txt"):
        list1 = line.strip()
        list2 = list1.split()
        for x in list2:
          if isPalindrome(x):
                list3.append(x)
                return list3

Comment: A sample of your `English.txt`?

Comment: You haven't shown us `isPalindrome()`, which is the heart of the entire program.  How can we help without seeing that?  You also haven't shown us the code which calls `findPalindrome()` and processes its results.

Comment: Okay, that's a function definition. It doesn't do _anything_ until you call it. Where and how do you do that? It also doesn't print _anything_. It _returns_ data. What are you doing with the value it returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are almos done:

```
from collections import Counter

def isPalindrome(s): 
    if (s == s[::-1] ): return True
    else: return False

def findPalindrome(): 
    list3=list() 
    for line in open("English.txt"): 
        list1 = line.strip() 
        list2 = list1.split() 
        for x in list2:
            if isPalindrome(x): 
                list3.append(x) 

    return list3 

palim_list = findPalindrome()
palim_counts = Counter(palim_list)
print palim_list
print palim_counts
```

Comment: it is showing output. but with every output it is showing 1 why?  AAAAAA': 1, 'ABA': 1, 'acca': 1, 'ADA': 1, 'addda': 1, 'AEA': 1, 'AFA': 1, 'affa': 1, 'aga': 1, 'AHA': 1, 'AIA': 1, 'AJA': 1, 'AKA': 1, 'ALA': 1, 'alula': 1, 'AMA': 1,

Comment: Perhaps because there are only one occurrence of each word inside the "English.txt" file?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're complicating things, to get all the palindrome from a file in a list, you could just iterate over its empty-lines-stripped-content and check if the string is equal to its inverted representation:

someFile:

```
kaak
okay
tired
alot
acca
```

**Hence**:

```
res = []
with open('someFile.txt', 'r') as fObj:
    content = [l.strip() for l in fObj.readlines() if l.strip()]    
    for line in content:
        if line == line[::-1]:
            res.append(line)
print(res)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['kaak', 'acca']
```

Comment: Guys I am sorry about my silly mistakes. I am not much familiar with coding.

Comment: @AJ Don't be sorry, we all make mistakes and then learn from them, what the community expects is to properly show your attempts, the crystal and complete snippet.

Comment: Why do you have `str()` wrap around `line` in the `if` check? They are already strings.

Comment: @Austin perks of working after a hectic drive. fixed, thank you!

Comment: I remember catching you for a similar issue before. Seems like perks of work are on daily basis. :P

Comment: @Austin haha, glad to have you on my back then! :)